# Spring Boot Actuator adding X-Frame-Options = DENY to all endpoints (particularly error endpoint)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am attempting to set the X-Frame-Options to DENY for all management endpoints, particularly the `/error` endpoint. I have the following in my application.properties of my Spring Boot application.

```
security.headers.frame=true
management.security.enabled=true
management.port=8001
```

When I go to `http://localhost:8001/error` I do not have the X-Frame-Options header, however the `http://localhost:8001/trace` endpoint does have the header. How do I configure my application.properties or what do I need to override to get that response header for the error endpoint?

Comment: I'm having the same issue - would love some guidance from the spring team :)

Answer (score 4):

Going through the current Spring Boot source (1.1.7.RELEASE), I don't see anyway that you can do what you want without totally doing away with the Security auto-configuration.

That is because in order for an endpoint to be eligible for the customized HTTP Headers (like `X-Frame-Options`) it needs to be a bean in the parent context (the one that is associated with the application on the normal port) that implements [MvcEndpoint](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/mvc/MvcEndpoint.java). Such beans are [HealthMvcEndpoint](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/mvc/HealthMvcEndpoint.java), [JolokiaMvcEndpoint](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/mvc/JolokiaMvcEndpoint.java) etc.

My statement adove can be viewed in code at [ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration.java) in the `ManagementWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure` method (`endpointHandlerMapping` is created from the `MvcEndpoint` implementation beans).

The error page for the management app, is [ManagementErrorEndpoint](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/mvc/ManagementErrorEndpoint.java) that is created in `errorEndpoint` of [EndpointWebMvcChildContextConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcChildContextConfiguration.java) which is triggered when the child context is created (due the inclusion of the management app), which is too late to be included in the endpoints that supported for HTTP Headers customization

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This is what I feared. As I'm new to the spring eco-system, I had gone into the source code and found this and could not figure out a way to get my custom headers on that endpoint.

Comment: @BrandonWilliams Your welcome! I really enjoyed searching through the source in order to answer this question. Gives valuable insights to Spring Boot internals!

Answer (score 2):

The /error endpoint is not an Actuator `Endpoint` and it's not secured by default (lots of errors can happen when a user is not authenticated). You could maybe make it available to anonymous users, but my guess is not even that would prevent some nasty infinite loops, where there is a mistake in the security configuration. I'm sure there's another way to add the header without Spring Security?